# Replace a physical drive that is part of RAID 1+0

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid10

I have a physical hard drive that has a status of imminent failure. It is part of a 4 x 1TB RAID 1+0. The controller is Smart Array B110i SATA RAID in Embedded Slot and the server is HP ML110 G7.

I already have a new 1TB HDD for replacement. How do I replace the drive that is about to fail? Do I just pullout the failing drive and insert the new drive? Not sure if this is correct. So please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. Shutdown the server. Pulled the power cord. Removed the drive marked with Predictive failure. Inserted the new drive. Turned on the server. Pressed F1 during POST to confirm that the logical drive will be rebuilt. Waited for 2 days for the logical drive to be completely rebuilt. And that's it.